# How can I determine which matrix libraries my R install is using?

Tags: r, build, lapack, blas, atlas

I am having a matrix error when using the computer cluster at my university that I cannot reproduce on my local machine.  I think it might be due to a difference of matrix libraries (BLAS, LAPACK, ATLAS, etc.).  I don't know much about these libraries other than what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858104/what-is-the-relation-between-blas-lapack-and-atlas), but I'm thinking there should be a way to get R to tell me which matrix libraries it was installed with (i.e. which ones it's using), analogous to sessionInfo() to tell me which version of R packages it's using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though there may not be an explicit R function for this, perhaps you can capitalize on shell commands (e.g., `file` and `ldd`) to get some clues without requiring rebuilding R nor root access on the cluster:

```
(rpath <- Sys.which("R"))
#            R
# "/usr/bin/R"
```

To make sure that `ldd` will work, see what type of file it is:

```
system2("file", rpath)
# /usr/bin/R: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

If yours shows an actual executable (such as `ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, ...`), then skip this one step.

```
script <- readLines(rpath)
script[grepl("/bin/", script)]
# [1] "#!/bin/bash"
# [2] "     if [ -x \"/usr/${libnn}/R/bin/exec/R\" ]; then"
# [3] "     elif [ -x \"/usr/${libnn_fallback}/R/bin/exec/R\" ]; then"
# [4] "## some systems have a more portable sed, e.g. /usr/xpg4/bin/sed on Solaris,"
# [5] "SED=/bin/sed"
# [6] "      exec sh \"${R_HOME}/bin/Rcmd\" \"${@}\" ;;"
# [7] "R_binary=\"${R_HOME}/bin/exec${R_ARCH}/R\""
```

This tells me that the actual executable is `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R` (or `/usr/lib64/...`). It is taking some inference, but it's a step. This is working for me with R-3.3.2 on ubuntu, so I can only assume it'll be similar on different OSes. If this is uninformative, you can also grep for `"/lib"` or `"/exec"` (or just examine the whole script file for other clues).

Once you know the path called by the script (or if it isn't a script to begin with), find the shared library dependencies:

```
system2("ldd", "/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R")
#         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcfadcd000)
#         libR.so => /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so (0x00007f746f615000)
#         libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f746f3eb000)
#         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f746f025000)
#         libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f746eda8000)
#         libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f746eaa2000)
#         libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f746e85b000)
#         libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f746e61d000)
#         liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f746e3fb000)
#         libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f746e1ea000)
#         libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f746dfd1000)
#         librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f746ddc9000)
#         libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f746dbc4000)
#         libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f746d9b5000)
#         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560abd5fa000)
#         libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f746d78b000)
```

The 5th line of this output suggests that R is using the BLAS library, specifically `libblas3`.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough and detailed answer.  I never would have figure it out on my own.  It's a shame that R doesn't have an "about me" function, like "R --version" , but maybe it could be called "R --buildoptions".

Comment: It's probably useful to note that if `system2("file", rpath)` shows an executable then  "skipping the next step" means calling `system2("ldd", rpath)`.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware there isn’t a specific function (especially not in base R) that will give you the BLAS version. R will most likely use the standard library that comes with your system (unless someone built it from source with a specific BLAS version).

You’d have to do it from the terminal, type

```
locate libblas.so
```

It’s probably going to be in `/usr/lib/libblas.so` or `/usr/lib64/libblas.so`, and the location is probably a symlink. So follow the links

```
ls -l /usr/lib/libblas.so
```

If you want to to change the symbolic links to point to a different BLAS library, you can do
`update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3gf` 
and select the version you want to use. This post explains it very nicely in more detail: https://www.r-bloggers.com/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/

Another way to definitely know what version you are using, would be to install whatever implementation of BLAS you want – for example OpenBLAS, and then replace the standard R BLAS library with a symlink to your new library. Make sure to install R with `--with-shared-blas` option, as explained in here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#BLAS
Then you just need to:

```
# navigate to your R directory
cd  …/path-to-R-installation/lib/R/lib
# backup the original 
mv libRblas.so libRblas.backup 
# create simlink
ln –s …/path-to-new-0blas-library/new-lib.so libRblas.so
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I guess also that @rcorty could use this to discover if the Blas really is the cause of problem. By installing a range of Blas libraries and updating symbolic link to test one at a time to see if it replicates the error.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am specifically interested in the situation where someone else, who I share a machine with, built R from source with a specified matrix math library, eg. ATLAS, BLAS, OpenBLAS, etc.  Apologies if I wasn't clear enough in my question.  I'm curious if I can figure out what he did.

Answer (score -5):

Is a bit of googling enough?:
http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2013/07/09/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for your response.  From my reading of that article, it provides information on how to build R with different matrix libraries, but doesn't help me figure out which matrix library was used in an existing build.